# Explanation of OASPL and SEL

Tags: acoustics, psychoacoustics

I have data of different SPL for different 1/3 center frequencies.
Is it correct to sum the pressures at a mean square basis of those SPL values (and then convert them back to SPL) to obtain the OASPL (Overall Sound Pressure Level)?
Furthermore, how to compute a SEL (Sound Exposure Level) from different OASPL over a time period? Just acoustically sum those OASPL values and divide the sum by the number of time steps?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can calculate it by summing all of the 3rd-octave band pressures. Keep in mind, that if the units are pressure then simple sum and conversion to the decibel scale is enough. However, if you have 3rd-octave band levels, then you have to calculate the anti-log of those values, sum them and then convert back to SPL.

Regarding the Sound Exposure Level, you can calculate it from the equivalent SPL $L_{eq}$:

$$SEL = L_{eq} + 10\log_{10}T $$

Where $T$ is the duration of the measurement in seconds. There is a simple intuition behind it. The $L_{eq}$ can be understood as the level of a constant signal, which has the same energy as the varying signal you’ve measured, with the same length. The $SEL$, on the other hand, is the same value, but for a signal that lasts 1 second.

I assume that you will calculate the sum of all pressures (in linear scale) for each of the time instants - you’ve called them OASPL (I don't like this name). Then all it takes to calculate the $SEL$ is to average them, convert to decibel scale and add the duration logarithm of the measurements duration.

---

Here is a complete example, so you can grasp what I am talking about.
To keep it simple, I will use octave bands instead (8 Hz - 16 kHz), which doesn't actually change anything.

Here are some unweighted levels ($L_{Zeq}$), logged every 0.1 second with total duration being 4.8 seconds.

```
67.2, 61.3, 46.9, 57.1, 57.7, 51.2, 44.4, 37.7, 35.5, 31.4, 23.2, 19.7
66.7, 60.0, 52.5, 58.0, 56.6, 50.5, 44.8, 38.6, 35.3, 32.7, 24.6, 20.0
64.7, 60.6, 65.8, 56.6, 57.0, 53.3, 45.4, 38.8, 35.0, 34.5, 24.6, 19.4
60.8, 60.5, 66.4, 55.9, 55.7, 52.7, 45.6, 38.7, 33.9, 29.8, 21.7, 19.6
57.3, 63.3, 54.8, 57.4, 58.1, 52.1, 43.8, 39.2, 34.5, 33.5, 26.5, 20.2
53.8, 67.2, 50.7, 56.0, 54.7, 50.4, 43.4, 37.7, 35.5, 35.4, 31.5, 23.8
53.3, 65.4, 51.0, 56.2, 55.0, 51.6, 45.4, 38.6, 35.0, 32.3, 28.5, 21.7
53.6, 61.7, 48.2, 56.1, 56.8, 52.5, 45.0, 39.7, 39.6, 35.5, 27.2, 21.1
52.4, 61.9, 49.7, 56.7, 56.1, 51.5, 45.2, 39.0, 35.5, 31.5, 24.8, 20.5
56.6, 62.2, 44.2, 57.8, 56.7, 50.8, 46.5, 58.0, 51.3, 47.9, 43.4, 40.9
57.6, 63.0, 44.7, 58.1, 55.1, 51.0, 58.3, 48.4, 33.6, 27.8, 22.0, 20.5
60.7, 61.6, 52.7, 56.5, 57.9, 56.7, 46.3, 36.9, 33.3, 29.2, 23.7, 19.9
61.2, 62.3, 51.5, 57.1, 57.2, 51.4, 57.9, 56.7, 49.4, 48.8, 51.0, 53.1
60.4, 59.7, 50.6, 56.7, 55.1, 55.9, 51.7, 38.5, 33.5, 27.5, 21.6, 19.4
60.6, 60.4, 52.8, 55.3, 55.9, 53.2, 43.7, 53.8, 52.0, 50.9, 47.6, 49.8
59.7, 67.1, 48.7, 56.0, 54.9, 51.1, 58.6, 55.0, 41.9, 36.7, 39.2, 28.4
60.5, 68.0, 46.3, 56.6, 55.9, 54.3, 55.9, 55.0, 61.3, 44.5, 43.2, 29.2
61.0, 66.4, 43.3, 57.6, 54.4, 56.9, 52.8, 50.3, 51.1, 36.5, 32.8, 20.5
62.3, 61.2, 44.5, 57.9, 52.3, 57.3, 45.3, 40.0, 43.8, 39.9, 34.5, 28.1
64.7, 59.2, 49.2, 59.0, 58.8, 51.0, 47.5, 52.3, 47.5, 44.9, 38.8, 28.6
66.0, 59.6, 53.2, 62.6, 57.2, 50.6, 46.5, 45.2, 40.7, 35.6, 27.2, 20.0
68.8, 60.3, 51.3, 63.7, 51.7, 48.2, 46.5, 38.6, 34.6, 28.7, 25.3, 21.9
70.2, 60.2, 49.5, 60.2, 54.6, 52.2, 47.8, 38.8, 33.0, 29.3, 29.0, 26.1
69.6, 58.6, 48.9, 60.9, 54.1, 51.0, 45.4, 38.1, 34.3, 31.1, 29.3, 24.1
68.8, 58.7, 47.3, 61.5, 53.2, 48.4, 44.8, 37.6, 35.9, 32.3, 29.2, 25.6
67.4, 61.4, 49.4, 61.3, 55.3, 49.8, 47.2, 40.1, 36.7, 32.8, 26.8, 20.9
68.4, 61.8, 61.3, 60.9, 52.6, 47.5, 45.0, 38.5, 36.3, 32.3, 25.7, 19.8
68.2, 61.9, 64.3, 61.5, 51.5, 49.3, 45.7, 37.8, 33.9, 28.3, 22.6, 19.2
68.9, 59.6, 61.1, 60.4, 54.2, 50.9, 44.2, 39.0, 34.1, 27.9, 22.5, 19.7
69.4, 59.5, 57.3, 59.8, 55.0, 51.4, 45.7, 38.8, 33.6, 29.3, 28.1, 20.7
69.3, 60.5, 54.1, 60.3, 51.7, 50.4, 45.2, 37.9, 34.3, 29.1, 25.4, 20.6
68.8, 59.4, 50.0, 60.3, 50.5, 51.7, 44.7, 36.5, 34.0, 29.3, 25.5, 20.0
67.5, 56.2, 49.4, 60.4, 53.2, 51.0, 47.0, 37.4, 33.5, 28.2, 23.0, 19.5
66.3, 53.8, 51.4, 61.4, 52.6, 50.2, 46.1, 37.0, 33.9, 29.8, 23.5, 20.2
65.1, 58.7, 52.3, 61.1, 51.2, 50.6, 45.6, 38.6, 34.5, 28.8, 21.4, 19.6
67.2, 59.6, 50.0, 60.9, 52.5, 48.4, 45.9, 38.9, 34.3, 31.0, 23.0, 19.9
67.1, 60.3, 50.9, 60.2, 53.4, 52.0, 45.7, 39.2, 35.3, 35.2, 27.2, 22.3
66.9, 61.2, 51.2, 60.4, 52.7, 52.1, 46.7, 38.4, 34.7, 31.1, 24.6, 20.8
65.3, 63.6, 52.1, 59.2, 55.6, 50.0, 46.9, 38.5, 34.4, 35.2, 28.3, 21.2
61.9, 65.7, 52.7, 59.4, 56.6, 50.3, 46.8, 39.7, 53.0, 46.8, 32.8, 26.1
59.7, 65.8, 52.6, 61.1, 54.0, 50.1, 44.1, 39.3, 45.0, 41.1, 28.8, 21.7
57.9, 63.7, 48.4, 60.6, 52.9, 51.5, 46.4, 41.3, 37.6, 35.3, 27.2, 20.9
57.4, 62.6, 48.4, 60.3, 55.2, 52.2, 45.7, 37.3, 34.6, 30.4, 25.4, 20.5
58.3, 61.1, 51.0, 59.9, 53.3, 48.7, 45.7, 37.3, 35.9, 31.5, 29.2, 21.6
60.9, 59.3, 51.4, 59.5, 53.3, 50.5, 46.7, 38.7, 36.3, 31.7, 28.6, 21.5
63.1, 59.7, 48.5, 60.1, 54.9, 51.4, 45.5, 37.8, 37.2, 34.4, 30.3, 22.8
62.5, 57.9, 48.4, 59.9, 54.9, 49.4, 45.1, 39.4, 40.3, 35.4, 30.5, 22.4
60.9, 59.6, 48.8, 59.9, 56.4, 50.7, 43.9, 46.2, 41.0, 39.5, 32.6, 25.0
```

Since this measurement had been performed using an SLM, I know the exact value of $SEL$, which is $75.3 \mathrm{dB}$.

Let's read it and calculate the instantaneous $L_{Zeq}$ for each frame (the thing that you call OASPL).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bands = [8.0 , 16.0, 31.5, 63.0, 125.0, 250.0, 500.0, 1000.0, 2000.0, 4000.0, 8000.0, 16000.0]
    oct_L = np.genfromtxt('octave.csv', delimiter=',')

    oct_P = np.power(10, oct_L/10)   # Anti-log to go back to linear domain
    frame_P = np.sum(oct_P, axis=1)  # Instantaneous pressure in each octave band

    Leq_dt = 10*np.log10(frame_P)    # Instantaneous SPL - OASPL

    Leq = 10*np.log10(np.mean(frame_P))  # Equivalent SPL

    T = oct_L.shape[0] * 0.1
    SEL = Leq + 10*np.log10(T)

    print(Leq_dt)
    print(SEL)
```

That returns the $SEL$ equal to 75.3 dB and per frame equivalent levels:

```
[ 69.   68.5  69.6  68.9  66.4  68.1  66.8  64.6  64.6  66.3  66.5  66.4
  67.7  65.4  66.1  69.1  70.3  68.7  66.5  67.7  68.8  70.6  71.2  70.6
  70.   69.5  70.5  71.   70.6  70.6  70.5  70.   68.8  68.   67.6  68.9
  68.9  68.9  68.6  68.6  68.2  66.6  66.1  65.3  65.4  66.6  65.9  65.8]
```